# HDFS: Read data from HDFS to parse XML files in HDFS using Python3

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, snakebite

I have about 1500 XML files in HDFS, each of them is about 2-3Gb. I need to write a python script to parse the XML files to perform MapReduce. However, I am facing issue to access the files in HDFS using python.

I tried the following script, and receive an error.

```
from snakebite.client import Client
def connection():
hadoop_client = Client('HDFS_hostname', 'HDFS_port', use_trash=False)
for x in hadoop_client.ls(['/']):
    print(x)
```

Following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/textmining/read_data_from_HDFS.py", line 5, in <module>
    from snakebite.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/snakebite/client.py", line 1473
    baseTime = min(time * (1L << retries), cap);
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the best recommended way to access files from HDFS using python?

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install snakebite-py3
```

this will help you to solve that issue...

Answer (score -1):

i came acroos the same issue. 
snakebite is not comaptible with python 3.x u can use it with python 2.